# Ansible loop related issues

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a playbook which has multiple roles and serial setup so that fist it's running on one machine then on the rest of them. In one of the roles I have the following tasks:

```
- name: getting dbnodes IP addresses
  local_action: shell echo  "{% for host in groups['dbnodes'] %}{{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }},{% endfor %}"
  run_once: true
  register: IPS
```

Basically what I want to do is to gather the IP addresses of all the hosts and register it with IPS for further usage. But the task is failing because of the serial (I think) with the following error.

`TASK [dbcluster : getting dbnodes IP addresses] ********************************
fatal: [162.220.52.190]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'action' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth0'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/tenon-delivery/ansible/roles/dbcluster/tasks/main.yml': line 52, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: getting dbnodes IP addresses\n  ^ here\n"}`

While running `ansible dbnode -s setup` I can see that the ansible_eth0 has a proper value. I don't understand why it is saying that it's undefined.

Any idea how to gather the facts on all machines in the same time while still having the option several tasks/handlers still being done serialized.

Answer (score 0):

`ansible_eth0` fact may be unknown at the time of your task run.

You may want to add *fact gathering* play at the very top of your playbook:

```
- hosts: dbnodes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="facts gathering"

- hosts: othernodes
  tasks:
    - name: getting dbnodes IP addresses
      ...
```

Comment: Your words about serial runs don't change anything. Make a separate play to collect all facts, then do everything else.

Comment: actually it does change cause if I disable the serial then the fact gathering is working. The question in this case is how to use variabled set in one playbook into another one.

Comment: You can't use facts from _one playbook_ in _another one_. Facts are persistent in one playbook only. This is why I tell you to make a separate play in your playbook that will only gather facts and nothing more. In subsequent plays during your playbook you may use all those facts in any way you want with serial runs or not.